# How to order date & month column correctly in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that looks like the below photo.

[image]table

I am trying to order **Month No** and **Month Name** correctly (starts from January), but the year and month no columns are in **Whole number** format.

None of the sorting methods is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a calculated column and sort your table by this new column

```
Year&Month =
'Table'[Year] & FORMAT ( 'Table'[Month No], "00" )
```